# Can I add a network prefab at runtime in Unity.Netcode?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer

I use Unity.Netcode. I want to add prefabs via script. Can I do that? I found nothing in the manual.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPWnz.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can call [AddNetworkPrefab](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager/index.html#methods) on `NetworkManager.Singleton`.

It's been added as of v1.0.0 of the docs.